# Find the best matching product version from a list of available product versions

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

How to return the best matching/next available  product versionId from a list of available product versions ?

*Here is the logic  based on the sample data in the table*

Look for the best matching version available  less than 10.10.20 and should return its versionID
eg1:GetVersion("10.10.20") should return 5 ( because in table there is no "10,10,20" major.minor.build combination available ,so it should look for the best matching version
here the next available version is 10.7.1  ie., versionID 5

eg2:GetVersion("7.0.0") should return 3 ( because in table there is no "7,0,0" major.minor.build combination available ,so it should look for next available matching version .here the
next available version is 6.2.1  ie., versionID 3

eg3:GetVersion("7.5.1") should return 4 ,here exact match is available soit should return versionid 4

```
 [Serializable]
    public class ProductVersions
    {
        [Key]
        public int Version_Id { get; set; }
        public int Major { get; set; }
        public int Minor { get; set; }
        public int Build { get; set; }
    }
```

Here is some sample data in my ProductVersions Table

```
    [version_id , Major,Minor,Build]
        1           3      0    1
        2           4     10    5
        3           6     2     1
        4           7     5     1
        5           10    7     1
        6           11    10   10
```

Here is my method that is expected to return best available product version

```
private int GetVersion(string versionNumber)
   {
    int version-id=0;

    version-id= //retrieve best matching version

     return version-id
    }
```

Comment: Can you please give a formal description of how "best matching" should work, examples aside? for instance, why if you query GetVersion("7.0.0") 3 is better than 4?

Comment: *Here is my method that is expected to return best available product version* When people on stackoverflow say you should *show your effort so far*, they don't mean *post an basically empty method body*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the build-in Version class, since it already implements the `<=` operator you are basically looking for, and also can handle the string parsing for you:

```
var data = new List<Version>()
{
     new Version(3,0,1),
     new Version(4,10,5),
     new Version(6,2,1),
     new Version(7,5,1),
     new Version(10,7,1),
     new Version(11,10,10)
};

var case1 = new Version("10.10.20");
// match1 is 5; the index of a List is 0-based, so we add 1
var match1 = data.FindLastIndex(d => d <= case1) + 1;

var case2 = new Version("7.0.0");
// match2 is 3
var match2 = data.FindLastIndex(d => d <= case2) + 1;

var case3 = new Version("7.5.1");
// match3 is 4
var match3 = data.FindLastIndex(d => d <= case3) + 1;
```

It should be trivial to convert your sequence of `ProductVersions` to a list of `Version` objects.

If you don't want to use the `Version` class for whatever reason, you can implement the `<=` (and all other missing operators) yourself:

```
public class ProductVersions
{
   //TODO error checking
   public int Version_Id { get; set; }
   public int Major { get; set; }
   public int Minor { get; set; }
   public int Build { get; set; }

   public ProductVersions(int major, int minor, int build)
   {
        Major=major;
        Minor=minor;
        Build=build;
   }

   public ProductVersions(string version)
   {
        var tmp = version.Split('.');
        Major = Int32.Parse(tmp[0]);
        Minor = Int32.Parse(tmp[1]);
        Build = Int32.Parse(tmp[2]);
   }

   public static bool operator == (ProductVersions a, ProductVersions b)
   {
        return a.Major==b.Major && a.Minor==b.Minor && a.Build==b.Build;
   }

   public static bool operator != (ProductVersions a, ProductVersions b)
   {
        return !(a==b);
   }

   public static bool operator <= (ProductVersions a, ProductVersions b)
   {
        if (a == b)
            return true;
        return a < b;
   }

   public static bool operator >= (ProductVersions a, ProductVersions b)
   {
        if (a == b)
            return true;
        return a > b;
   }

   public static bool operator < (ProductVersions a, ProductVersions b)
   {
        if(a.Major==b.Major)
            if(a.Minor==b.Minor)
                return a.Build < b.Build;
            else
                return a.Minor < b.Minor;
        else
            return a.Major < b.Major;
   }

   public static bool operator > (ProductVersions a, ProductVersions b)
   {
        if(a.Major==b.Major)
            if(a.Minor==b.Minor)
                return a.Build > b.Build;
            else
                return a.Minor > b.Minor;
        else
            return a.Major > b.Major;
   }
```

And a simple test:

```
var data = new List<ProductVersions>()
{
     new ProductVersions(3,0,1)    { Version_Id = 1},
     new ProductVersions(4,10,5)   { Version_Id = 2},
     new ProductVersions(6,2,1)    { Version_Id = 3},
     new ProductVersions(7,5,1)    { Version_Id = 4},
     new ProductVersions(10,7,1)   { Version_Id = 5},
     new ProductVersions(11,10,10) { Version_Id = 6}
};

// ensure data is sorted by version
data.Sort((a,b) => a > b ? 1 : a < b ? -1 : 0);

var case1 = new ProductVersions("10.10.20");
// match1 is 5
var match1 = data.Last(d => d <= case1).Version_Id;

var case2 = new ProductVersions("7.0.0");
// match2 is 3
var match2 = data.Last(d => d <= case2).Version_Id;

var case3 = new ProductVersions("7.5.1");
// match3 is 4
var match3 = data.Last(d => d <= case3).Version_Id;
```

Answer (score 1):

I like Dominic's answer using the version class (why invent when it exists?)  But in case you are wondering here is how to do it without using the Version class and you assume the list is already sorted (so you don't need to sort it like he did).

(TL;DR)

```
 // assume verArray is already ordered (this would need to be sorted otherwise.)
 // this where checks for less than or equal to.
 int result = verArray.Where(v => (v.Major < major) ||
                                  (v.Major == major && v.Minor < minor) ||
                                  (v.Major == major && v.Minor == minor && v.Build <= build))
                      .Last().Version_Id;
```

The full code and test:

```
public ProductVersions[]verArray = {
      new ProductVersions() { Version_Id = 1, Major = 3, Minor = 0, Build = 1 },
      new ProductVersions() { Version_Id = 2, Major = 4, Minor = 10, Build = 5 },
      new ProductVersions() { Version_Id = 3, Major = 6, Minor = 2, Build = 1 },
      new ProductVersions() { Version_Id = 4, Major = 7, Minor = 5, Build = 1 },
      new ProductVersions() { Version_Id = 5, Major = 10, Minor = 7, Build = 1 },
      new ProductVersions() { Version_Id = 6, Major = 11, Minor = 10, Build = 10 },
  };

void Main()
{
  string test = "10.10.20";
  Console.WriteLine(test + " gives "+GetVersion(test));

  test = "7.0.0";
  Console.WriteLine(test + " gives "+GetVersion(test));

  test = "7.5.1";
  Console.WriteLine(test + " gives "+GetVersion(test));
}

private int GetVersion(string versionNumber)
{
  string [] input = versionNumber.Split(".".ToCharArray());

  int major = int.Parse(input[0]);
  int minor = int.Parse(input[1]);
  int build = int.Parse(input[2]);

  // assume verArray is already ordered (this would need to be sorted otherwise.
  int result = verArray.Where(v => (v.Major < major) ||
                                   (v.Major == major && v.Minor < minor) ||
                                   (v.Major == major && v.Minor == minor && v.Build <= build))
                       .Last().Version_Id;

  return result;
}

public class ProductVersions
{
  public int Version_Id { get; set; }
  public int Major { get; set; }
  public int Minor { get; set; }
  public int Build { get; set; }
}
```

This returns the following:

```
10.10.20 gives 5
7.0.0 gives 3
7.5.1 gives 4
```

Answer (score -3):

I just checked for the samples you gave. This code works for me.

```
private int getver(int m, int n, int b)
{
    List<ProductVersions> pv = new List<ProductVersions>();
    pv.Add(new ProductVersions { Version_Id = 3, Major = 6, Minor = 2, Build = 1 });
    pv.Add(new ProductVersions { Version_Id = 4, Major = 7, Minor = 5, Build = 1 });
    pv.Add(new ProductVersions { Version_Id = 5, Major = 10, Minor = 7, Build = 1 });
    pv.Add(new ProductVersions { Version_Id = 6, Major = 11, Minor = 10, Build = 10 });

    int mm = m;
    if (m == 0)
        mm = int.MaxValue;
    int nn = n;
    if (n == 0)
        nn = int.MaxValue;
    int bb = b;
    if (b == 0)
        bb = int.MaxValue;
    var v = pv.FindAll(mj => mj.Major <= m).FindAll(mn => n == 0 ? mn.Major <= mm - 1 && mn.Minor <= nn : mn.Minor <= n).FindAll(bl => b == 0 ? bl.Minor <= nn - 1 && bl.Build <= bb : bl.Build <= b).Last().Version_Id;

    return v;
}
```

I am trying to shrink the list based on the criteria from major, minor and build levels and getting the last entity of the list. Here I assume that the list is sorted based on these values.

Comment: Your getver is taking 3 ints not a string.

Comment: Is the question is about string and int params? See that I am not giving that code that is going to be placed in production environment. I am trying to help with some algorithm to sort out the problem.

Comment: The question was also about Linq -- but your answer only works with `List<T>`, using `Where()` would make it "Linqy".

Answer (score -3):

I found this one a quick and simple way, but with some limitations.

```
    var v = from p in pv
            select new { version = p.Version_Id, val = p.Major * 100000000 + p.Minor * 10000 + p.Build };
    int vver=v.ToList().FindAll(pp => pp.val <= m * 100000000 + n * 10000 + b).Last().version;
```

Comment: What is `pv`, `m`, `n` and `b`?

Comment: AFAICT this will fail if build or minor version are < 10000 and will overflow and fail on between version 21 and version 22

Comment: Yes it fails. And I have mentioned it on the top. I tried a different variant for the other code snippet I have posted. I should have mentioned it.

Comment: Then you should have edited this question -- why leave a bad answer?  The goal here is to have good answers not bad ones.